# flutter how to manually push data from firestore and save in sqflite

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, push, sqflite

I have a firebase cloud database with a document that contains roughly 200 entries (Strings). These entries will only change every few weeks by a bit.

In order to save money (i.e. read and writes in firebase), I would like to push this list once in a while to my app and have it stored in the phone's sqflite database for further use in my app.

Is there a way to "manually" push that list (e.g. once a month) from the cloud database to my app and save it on the device's database? I searched for hours for a solution but nothing seems to fit.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a personal or public app? Have you thought about creating a button that activates this process? Since the updated data is on your phone (if I understand correctly) then you can sync it with the database OR download from the database

Comment: Hi, it s a public app and I would therefore like to control when I send the data to the app